# Why is my DotNetOpenAuth consumer not respecting the version 1.0a?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am building an OAuth service provider using DotNetOpenAuth, and to test it I have modified the sample wcf consumer to simply call a plain http endpoint.  The token request works fine, but when I request access to a protected resource, I get the following protocol execption:

```
The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages.AuthorizedTokenRequest message: oauth_verifier
```

When I look at the log output on my service provider I see this:

```
Error while performing basic validation of AuthorizedTokenRequest with these message parts:
oauth_token: pgzjBIs0pKCeDIcaIinyrV5Jhi0=
oauth_consumer_key: sampleconsumer
oauth_nonce: TM0Rc8kg
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
oauth_signature: zmpxK5c69n1VzTEEcrnnd4e+qYI=
oauth_version: 1.0
oauth_timestamp: 1305067751
```

Notice the oauth_version: 1.0, even though I have specified ProtocolVersion.V10a when I create the consumer.

If I specify ProtocolVersion.V10 on both sides I get this exception:

```
Expected message DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages.AccessProtectedResourceRequest but received DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages.AuthorizedTokenRequest instead.
```

Here is the consumer code to get the token (this is straight from the sample code):

```
WebConsumer consumer = this.CreateConsumer();
UriBuilder callback = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
callback.Query = null;
string[] scopes = (from item in this.scopeList.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                   where item.Selected
                   select item.Value).ToArray();
string scope = string.Join("|", scopes);
var requestParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "scope", scope } };
var response = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback.Uri, requestParams, null);
consumer.Channel.Send(response);
```

Here is my consumer code that is failing:

```
var accessToken = Session["WcfAccessToken"] as string;
var consumer = CreateConsumer();
var serviceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://mymachine/test/getUserName", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest);
var httpRequest = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(serviceEndpoint, accessToken);
var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

In my service provider I call serviceProvider.ReadProtectedResourceAuthorization(); and it fails with the exception I mentioned above.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you beef up your question to include the source code on the consumer that actually obtains the tokens in the first place?

Comment: I added the call the get authorization, as I mentioned in my question, that part is using the OAuthConsumer SampleWcf.aspx page from the samples that come with DotNetOpenAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part, I was returning the wrong TokenType, from my IServiceProviderTokenManager.  The correct logic is shown in the service provider sample, and looks something like this:

```
if (tokenObject.State == TokenAuthorizationState.AccessToken)
    return TokenType.AccessToken;
return TokenType.RequestToken;
```